# Jasper Reports - remove buttons from input control

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've been digging all over Jasper documentation and can't find the answer.

Currently for our reports, we have a simple input control, Date.  When this launches, I am given a date control and at the bottom, I get series of useless button choices...

Apply, OK, Reset, Cancel, Save

Can anyone help me get these removed? Just want OK and Cancel.  I looked at DefaultParametersForm.jsp but am having a hard time finding anything useful there.  I'm an amateur jsp programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We removed the Cancel button from the input control popup, we found it in the file inputControls.jsp in the jsp/templates directory.

You should find the apply, ok, reset and save button here also.

Comment: Thank you!!! We have the pro version and Jasper support wanted to charge us for this info.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know off-hand how to remove the buttons, but these buttons are not all useless.  Reset clears your fields back to their defaults (blank if no default).

When you are using the Control Layout 1, you may think the Apply and OK button do the same thing but they don't.  Apply will run the report with the set parameters, but will not get rid of the dialog box.  OK runs apply and removes the dialog as well.  (Note that the dialog can be dragged out of the way.)

If you switch to one of the other Control Layouts (I like 4), then the OK button goes away b/c there is no longer a dialog.  You will only get Apply, Reset, and Cancel.

Comment: I understand they have different purpose but they are a nuisance for the way we're using it.  Certain buttons really should have been omitted for different layouts. We are using them as a "pop-up" only and in that scenario, apply is useless.  However, it's the default button.

Comment: Also, not everyone needs the "save" button, in my opinion.

Comment: Having "reset" button forced on everyone is a bit extreme. Most common reports are with one... or at most two... input parameters.  I would much rather not have a reset button in that case.  Reset is only really helpful if you have a ton of inputs... ie. 10.

Comment: Sorry to be venting. Jasper can be a bit frustrating at times. None of these comments were directed at you... well, unless you're one of the developers for Jasper. ;)